# Как присвоить правильно переменную

Tags: javascript

`$('span.bol').text(bol-k);` делаю так

```
var r=$('span.bol').text(bol-k);
```

не получается, поправьте пожалуйста

Comment: А что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Текст - в кавычках. var r=$('span.bol').text('bol-k'); Без кавычек - это не текст а имя переменной (недопустимое к слову)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, на самом деле это _разница двух переменных_ :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну да) Просто когда хотят минус а не дефис, его хотя бы пробелами отбивают. Чего хотел автор (строчку разность или переменную с дефисом) остается лишь гадать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить текст из `span.bol`:

```
var r = $('span.bol').text();
```

Чтобы присвоить `span.bol` значение из переменной:

```
var some = 'Some string';
$('span.bol').text(some);
```

Чтобы присвоить `span.bol` строку:

```
var r = $('span.bol').text('Some string');
```